# How can i draw a line from A point to B point

Tags: three.js

How can I draw a line from A (rectangle) to B (sphere) with threejs?

How can be followed the rotated sphere with mouse movement.

Here is what I want to do:

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try THREE.Shape

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/extras/core/Shape

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html

or create a 3d model of the line and work with it